# iotop fields on missing SWAPIN and IO columns on AlmaLinux 8

Tags: centos, alma-linux, iotop

I am using `iotop` to monitor disk activity and on AlmaLinux 8 systems, `iotop` does not have all fields.

Here are the columns on AlmaLinux 8

```
PID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ DISK WRITE>    COMMAND
```

Here are the columns on CentOS 6/7

```
PID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
```

How do I make `iotop` display SWAPIN and IO> by default.

It also showing unavailable when I run the following:

```
[root@alma8-dev test]# iotop -botqk
18:22:09 Total DISK READ :       0.00 K/s | Total DISK WRITE :       0.00 K/s
18:22:09 Actual DISK READ:       0.00 K/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       0.00 K/s
    TIME    TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN      IO    COMMAND
18:22:11 Total DISK READ :       0.00 K/s | Total DISK WRITE :       0.00 K/s
18:22:11 Actual DISK READ:       0.00 K/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       0.00 K/s
18:22:12 Total DISK READ :       0.00 K/s | Total DISK WRITE :      64.94 K/s
18:22:12 Actual DISK READ:       0.00 K/s | Actual DISK WRITE:      64.94 K/s
b'18:22:12    2294 be/3 root        0.00 K/s   64.94 K/s ?unavailable?  d3 flusher-0 pick0 LINUX'
b'18:22:12  849204 be/4 root        0.00 K/s    0.00 K/s ?unavailable?  [kworker/1:3-events]'
```

Here's the kernel config:

```
[root@alma8-dev test]#  egrep 'CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT|CONFIG_TASK_IO_ACCOUNTING|CONFIG_TASKSTATS|CONFIG_VM_EVENT_COUNTERS' /boot/config-4.18.0-425.10.1.e_7.x86_64 CONFIG_TASKSTATS=y CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT=y CONFIG_TASK_IO_ACCOUNTING=y CONFIG_VM_EVENT_COUNTERS=y
```

Comment: Can you ensure that in the .config of your AlmaLinux 8 running kernel  CONFIG_TASK_DELAY_ACCT and CONFIG_TASK_IO_ACCOUNTING are set ?

Comment: I've updated my post. Is there anything else I can look at or try?

Comment: Does *vmstat* report anything in si,so,bi,bo columns ?

Comment: Yes, vmstat reports all the files mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Install `iotop-c` instead of `iotop`

```
dnf install iotop-c
```

Run `iotop-c` and the output is as below

```
  Total DISK READ:    0.00 B/s ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ |   Total DISK WRITE:  588.24 M/s ⣶⣶⣾⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
Current DISK READ:    0.00 B/s ⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ | Current DISK WRITE:  585.24 M/s ⣿⣿⣷⠀⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
TID     PRIO USER      DISK READ   DISK WRITE  SWAPIN   IOGRAPH[IO]▽COMMAND
  465   be/4 root         0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s   0.00 %  53.42 % ⣶⣤⣦⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀  kworker/u2:3+flush-253:0                                              ▲
 6332   be/4 slee         0.00 B/s  588.24 M/s   0.00 %  21.82 % ⣀⣠⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀  dd                                                                    █
 6246   be/4 root         0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s   0.00 %   0.00 % ⠀⠀⢀⢀⢀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀  kworker/0:1-ata_sff                                                   █
 5792   be/4 root         0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s   0.00 %   0.00 % ⢀⢀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀  kworker/0:2-events                                                    ▃
    1   be/4 root         0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s   0.00 %   0.00 % ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀  systemd
    2   be/4 root         0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s   0.00 %   0.00 % ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀  kthreadd
    3   be/0 root         0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s   0.00 %   0.00 % ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀  rcu_gp
```